# Log transformation in case of skewness

Tags: normality-assumption

I would like to log-transform my dependent variable because of a highly skewed distribution. None of my cases have a 0 on the variable, but a 1 occurs commonly.

Could it be problematic that the log-transformation turns the 1 into a 0 (I would like to run a fixed effects linear regression afterwards)? In other words, may it be advisable to calculate variable+1 before transformation?

Comment: Is your model afraid of responses that equal zero?  If not, what would the problem with a zero be?

Comment: SImilar question at http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1383703-log-transformation-of-bound-regressor Note that a distribution with an upper limit of 1, many 1s and no zeros is, on the face of it, left skewed so that log transformation can only make such skewness worse. In any case, symmetrical distribution of a predictor is not an assumption in regression.  Whether transformation helps otherwise we can't tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would not be a problem that the log transformation turns the 1 into a 0.

The **only** reason that a 0 is not allowed in the pre-transformed data is because the log is mathematically undefined.

However, as  @kjetilbhalvorsen noted, if you are using the model for prediction on new cases, you would have to ensure they do not have a pre-transformed value of zero.

Comment: If you want to use the estimated model for predictions with new data, and 0 values could occur in the future new data, then it would be a problem ..,

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen excellent point!  I should add that